# Can a light absorbing bulb-like thing be made?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation

A bulb emits light.

So can a bulb-like thing or anything be made such that it absorbs all/most of the light when turned on?

For example, when room is dark we switch on bulb and it spreads light. Let a room already be bright with daylight, so we turn on the light absorbent bulb/machine and it makes the room dark.

Here, light refers to visible light. But if this kind of device could be made, it could be extended to other lights too.

Comment: Yeah, a black object.

Comment: No not completely because all the light might not be falling on that so called "light-absorbing" bulb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A light bulb is a source of light continually emitting photons .  But light, built up by photons, is not a fluid, so that a corresponding sink   or a pump can pull it in. Photons at first order,  do not interact with each other, they can be absorbed given the corresponding energy levels in the atoms of the surfaces they impinge on.

Visible light can be absorbed by surfaces only if the light hits the surface. You could make a room with all black surfaces , which  would absorb all light, but not in the sense of a bulb/sink. Anyway if there is no continuous source of light, the existing photons are extremely rapidly absorbed by any walls, that is how dark rooms for photography work.